# How to write test sets to test the decision in the program in Python?

Tags: python, testing

I have been programming in Python for a month but I have never written a test case. I am trying to write 2 test sets to the test decision of my following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def books():
    a = input("Enter number of books:")
    inp = int(a)
    if inp==0:
        print("You earned 0 points")
    elif inp==1:
        print("You earned 5 points")
    elif inp==2:
        print("You earned 15 points")
    elif inp==3:
        print("You earned 30 points")
    elif inp==4:
        print("You earned 60 points")
    else:
        print("No Negatives")

books()
```

How do I write 2 test sets to test the decision for this program? Thanks!

Comment: why do you want a parameter in function `books`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edits for second version of the question:

```
def books(): 

    points = [0,5,15,30,60];    #  list of the points
    inp = 0;

    while inp < 0 or inp >= len(points):
        a = input("Enter number of books:") 
        inp = int(a)

    print("You earned",points[inp],"points") 

books()
```

You will be able to avoid the list if there is a direct correlation between the number of books and the number of points, but I don't know your algorithm for that.

If the values for `inp` were strings then you can use a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But seems like I have posted the wrong code. I have edited my question. Can u please look at it and edit your answer too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a test example. I'll caveat this by saying that this was done in Python 2.7, but I believe it will work in 3 as well (all I did was change the print statement to a function - not sure if the rest works :) ). I made a few edits to your code (as cdarke mentions, there are easier ways to set the number of points, but I'll keep this close to your original code so you can see the steps you could take to test it). Here is your code, with a few modifications (commented):

```
def Books(num_books):
    # We let books take a parameter so that we can test it with different
    # input values.
    try:
      # Convert to int and then choose your response
      num_books = int(num_books)
      if num_books < 0:
          response = "No Negatives"
      elif num_books == 0:
          response = "You earned 0 points"
      elif num_books == 1:
          response = "You earned 5 points"
      elif num_books == 2:
          response = "You earned 15 points"
      elif num_books == 3:
          response = "You earned 30 points"
      elif num_books == 4:
          response = "You earned 60 points"
      else:
          response = "That's a lot of books"

    except ValueError:
        # This could be handled in a better way, but this lets you handle
        # the case when a user enters a non-number (and lets you test the
        # exception)
        raise ValueError("Please enter a number.")

    return response


def main():
    # Here we wrap the main code in the main function to prevent it from
    # executing when it is imported (which is what happens in the test case)

    # Get the input from the user here - this way you can bypass entering a
    # number in your tests.
    a = input("Enter number of books: ")

    # Print the result
    print(Books(a))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then the test, which you can simply run as `python my_program_test.py`:

```
import my_program
import unittest

class MyProgramTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def testBooks(self):
      # The results you know you want
      correct_results = {
          0: "You earned 0 points",
          1: "You earned 5 points",
          2: "You earned 15 points",
          3: "You earned 30 points",
          4: "You earned 60 points",
          5: "That's a lot of books"
          }

      # Now iterate through the dict, verifying that you get what you expect
      for num, value in correct_results.iteritems():
          self.assertEqual(my_program.Books(num), value)


  def testNegatives(self):
      # Test a negative number to ensure you get the right response
      num = -3
      self.assertEqual(my_program.Books(num), "No Negatives")


  def testNumbersOnly(self):
      # This is kind of forced in there, but this tests to make sure that
      # the proper exception is raised when a non-number is entered
      non_number = "Not a number"
      self.assertRaises(ValueError, my_program.Books, non_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: @New Folder: this answer is for Python 2, judging from your `print` statements you are probably using Python 3.  Note that `raw_input` is old Python for `input`.  (Although I notice that @RocketDonkey used the function version of `print`, which is normally only available in old Python with `from __future__ import print_function`)

Comment: @cdarke Yeah, I was writing it from Python 2.7 and was trying to adjust the code so it would work for him with 3 - is there anything in mine that wouldn't work with 3 (I'll fix raw_input, good point)? I guess I should start using it at some point :)

Comment: Nah, just the `input` SFAIK.  Sorry to be picky.  There are some changes in exception handling, and some new features in `unittest`, but I think the existing should work so far as you have used them.

Comment: @cdarke Awesome, thanks for pointing that out. As for being picky, that's what keeps this site good :)